# Active Directory last logon replication across AD servers

Tags: active-directory

We need to run a query that will automatically disable an account after n days of inactivity.  I was told that since we have several AD servers that if a user logs on, let's say to ADserver1 the last logon information is not replicated to ADserver2..  How can I have the last logon information replicated across all AD Servers?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Powershell script written by Richard Mueller that I've found helpful. It queries ALL of your AD servers in your domain and reports the most recent logon time for all users/computers, so some hand editing may be necessary to meet your needs. Makes a good starting point though.

```
# PSLastLogon.ps1
# PowerShell script to determine when each user in the domain last
# logged on.
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2011 Richard L. Mueller
# Hilltop Lab web site - http://www.rlmueller.net
# Version 1.0 - March 16, 2011
#
# This program queries every Domain Controller in the domain to find the
# largest (latest) value of the lastLogon attribute for each user. The
# last logon dates for each user are converted into local time. The
# times are adjusted for daylight savings time, as presently configured.
#
# You have a royalty-free right to use, modify, reproduce, and
# distribute this script file in any way you find useful, provided that
# you agree that the copyright owner above has no warranty, obligations,
# or liability for such use.

Trap {"Error: $_"; Break;}

$D = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()
$Domain = [ADSI]"LDAP://$D"
$Searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$Searcher.PageSize = 200
$Searcher.SearchScope = "subtree"


# Switch this to search for computers or users
$Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer))"
# $Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=user))"

$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName") > $Null
$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("lastLogon") > $Null

# Create hash table of users and their last logon dates.
$arrUsers = @{}

# Enumerate all Domain Controllers.
ForEach ($DC In $D.DomainControllers)
{
    $Server = $DC.Name
    $Searcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://$Server/" + $Domain.distinguishedName
    $Results = $Searcher.FindAll()
    ForEach ($Result In $Results)
    {
        $DN = $Result.Properties.Item("distinguishedName")
        $LL = $Result.Properties.Item("lastLogon")
        If ($LL.Count -eq 0)
        {
            $Last = [DateTime]0
        }
        Else
        {
            $Last = [DateTime]$LL.Item(0)
        }
        If ($Last -eq 0)
        {
            $LastLogon = $Last.AddYears(1600)
        }
        Else
        {
            $LastLogon = $Last.AddYears(1600).ToLocalTime()
        }
        If ($arrUsers.ContainsKey("$DN"))
        {
            If ($LastLogon -gt $arrUsers["$DN"])
            {
                $arrUsers["$DN"] = $LastLogon
            }
        }
        Else
        {
            $arrUsers.Add("$DN", $LastLogon)
        }
    }
}

# Output latest last logon date for each user.
$Users = $arrUsers.Keys
ForEach ($DN In $Users)
{
    $Date = $arrUsers["$DN"]
    If ($Date -eq "01/01/1601 00:00:00") {$Date = "1/1/1900 12:00:00"}
    $DN = [regex]::Match($DN,'CN=([^,]+)').Groups[1].Value 
    "`"$DN`",$Date"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Last login information is automatically replicated between domain controllers.

If it's not in your environment, then replication is broken, and retrieving last login times for users is the very least of your problems, given that your AD implementation is irreparably broken (or will be soon when your domain controllers start tombstoning each other).

Incidentally, [it seems that this article on the lastLogontimestamp might be of interest to you](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works.aspx).

> The lastLogontimeStamp attribute is not updated every time a user or computer logs on to the domain. The decision to update the value is based on the current date minus the value of the (ms-DS-Logon-Time-Sync-Interval attribute minus a random percentage of 5). If the result is equal to or greater than lastLogontimeStamp the attribute is updated. There are no special considerations for replication of lastLogontimeStamp. If the attribute is updated it is replicated like any other attribute update.

[As might this one, on the Last Logon *Attribute*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676823%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> This attribute is not replicated and is maintained separately on each domain controller in the domain. To get an accurate value for the user's last logon in the domain, the Last-Logon attribute for the user must be retrieved from every domain controller in the domain. The largest value that is retrieved is the true last logon time for that user.

Comment: Supporting information can be found here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works.aspx

Comment: The lastLogon attribute is not replicated. Never was and never will be. Starting with Server 2003, a new attribute was added, lastLogontimeStamp, which is replicated.The bad news is that not all logon events update this new attribute. So it *may* have the most recent logon time. The script below works around this by querying *all* the AD servers for the lastLogon attribute, which is always updated (but never replicated), and comparing them to determine the most recent.